# ft2font can be imported from matplotlib in Anaconda prompt terminal, but it failed in python script from Ecelipse/pydev

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, matplotlib, pydev

I try to run a python 3.7 script in Eclipse/pydev on win 7.

But, I got error:

```
   import matplotlib.ft2font
   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

If I run :
    import matplotlib.ft2font

in Anaconda prompt, it works well. But, if I run it in python script from Ecelipse/pydev, it got this error.

```
  Ecelipse Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)
            Build id: 20160613-1800
```

Conda info:

```
  active environment : base
  active env location : C:\MyProgram\Anaconda3p7
      shell level : 1
    conda version : 4.6.3
    conda-build version : 3.17.6
   python version : 3.7.1.final.0
```

I cannot find any helpful posts online.

My matplotlib version is 3.0.2

Could anyone help about this ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

This https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6689 helped me by uninstalling matplotlib from conda and installing it with pip instead.

1. Open an elevated Anaconda prompt (if you installed Anaconda for all users)
2. `conda uninstall matplotlib`
3. `pip install matplotlib`